# PSRemoting parameter RunAsAdministrator 'parameter set cannot be resolved' error

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a simple get-wmiobject cmdlet remotely, and it's returning an 'access is denied' error. The client is on domain A, server is on domain B, and user on Domain A doesn't have access to Server, so this part makes sense.

So I tried to create a PSsession with Domain B Creds on the client. If i RDP into server with these same creds, the cmdlet runs just fine. However, using the PSsession, it still returns an 'access is denied'.

So I tried adding -RunAsAdministrator to Both the 'new-pssession' and 'enter-pssession' cmdlets

But both give the following error:

`Enter-PSSession : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`

If i remove the -RunAsAdministrator, it connects, but then I run into "Access is Denied" again. So I know it's this parameter that is causing this issue.

The only thing I can think of is that the User is already an Admin, so maybe by telling it twice that I'm an Admin is causing issues. But my understanding is that the -RunAsAdministrator parameter is simply telling the PSsession to run powershell with Admin rights.

Even with invoke-command i've gotten this error. -RunAsAdministrator just doesn't work for me.

I added my client IP to the server trustedhosts list - same errors.

Thanks

Comment: according to the MSDocs page for `new-pssession` the `-RunAsAdministrator` parameter is only valid in ONE parameter set. so ... what is the entire command you are using?

Comment: Have you tried `-Credential(Get-Credential)`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey the entire command: $wsession = new-pssession -computername $computer -credential $creds -RunAsAdministrator

Comment: @JustinBeagley - _please_, always add new info to your Question so that it will be seen by all who want to help - and much more easily read, too. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lee_Dailey points out, there is only one syntax for `New-PSSession` and `Enter-PSSession` that allows the `-RunAsAdministrator` switch to be used:

```
Enter-PSSession [-ContainerId] <string> [-ConfigurationName <string>] [-RunAsAdministrator] [<CommonParameters>]
```

You can see this by running `Get-Help Enter-PSSession` or `Get-Command Enter-PSSession -Syntax` in PowerShell to see what other parameters are compatible with the `-RunAsAdministrator` switch.

```
PS C:\Users\TMTech> get-command Enter-PSSession -Syntax

Enter-PSSession [-ComputerName] <string> [-EnableNetworkAccess] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-ConfigurationName <string>] [-Port <int>] [-UseSSL] [-ApplicationName <string>] [-SessionOption <PSSessionOption>] [-Authentication <AuthenticationMechanism>] [-CertificateThumbprint <string>] [<CommonParameters>]

Enter-PSSession [[-Session] <PSSession>] [<CommonParameters>]

Enter-PSSession [[-ConnectionUri] <uri>] [-EnableNetworkAccess] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-ConfigurationName <string>] [-AllowRedirection] [-SessionOption <PSSessionOption>] [-Authentication <AuthenticationMechanism>] [-CertificateThumbprint <string>] [<CommonParameters>]

Enter-PSSession [-InstanceId <guid>] [<CommonParameters>]

Enter-PSSession [[-Id] <int>] [<CommonParameters>]

Enter-PSSession [-Name <string>] [<CommonParameters>]

Enter-PSSession [-VMId] <guid> [-Credential] <pscredential> [-ConfigurationName <string>] [<CommonParameters>]

Enter-PSSession [-VMName] <string> [-Credential] <pscredential> [-ConfigurationName <string>] [<CommonParameters>]

Enter-PSSession [-ContainerId] <string> [-ConfigurationName <string>] [-RunAsAdministrator] [<CommonParameters>]
```

You may want to consider just running `Get-WmiObject` on the local computer to get info from the remote computer using creds for the remote computer. You may also have to use the `-EnableAllPrivileges` switch, depending on what you're accessing. Something like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server -EnableAllPrivileges -Credential $Creds
```